# What is the validity of the access token granted by Dropbox API (OAuth v1) and how to refresh it?

Tags: java, oauth, dropbox, dropbox-api

I read a thread on the dropbox forum [here](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=80430). But I'm still confused as for how long the token is valid and do I need to refresh it and **how**. My application needs to perform some scheduled operations on the users files offline, so I need to have a longer access, say for a week without the need of the user being asked to grant access again.

Answer (score 15):

The [Dropbox API Authentication Tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#python) would seem to indicate that access tokens are valid until the user uninstalls your app, or explicitly revokes the grant via the Dropbox page.

Comment: Yep: _"The access token is all you'll need for all future API requests on behalf of this user ... By storing the access token, you won't need to go through these steps again unless the user reinstalls your app or revokes access via the Dropbox website."_